# How to dynamically create HTML tags in header of all the languages and regions variants of a page?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, internationalization

I would like to add `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="lang_code"... >` elements to my pages headers to tell all the language and region variants of a page.

**Example** for the `homepage` header:

```html
<link rel="alternate" hrefLang="en" href="https://WEBSITE_URL/" />
<link rel="alternate" hrefLang="de" href="https://WEBSITE_URL/de" />
<link rel="alternate" hrefLang="nl" href="https://WEBSITE_URL/nl" />
```

**Example** for the `about-us` header:

```html
<link rel="alternate" hrefLang="en" href="https://WEBSITE_URL/about-us" />
<link rel="alternate" hrefLang="de" href="https://WEBSITE_URL/de/über-uns" />
<link rel="alternate" hrefLang="nl" href="https://WEBSITE_URL/nl/over-ons" />
```

And repeat this in every page with its corresponding path in that language. Is it possible to create it dynamically with Next.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can generate the `<link>`s dynamically based on your locales inside the custom `_app`. This way the logic applies to all pages of the app, and updates on client-side navigations.

```js
// pages/_app.js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Head from 'next/head'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const router = useRouter()

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                {router.locales.map((locale) => {
                    return (
                        <link
                            key={locale}
                            rel="alternate"
                            hrefLang={locale}
                            href={`https://WEBSITE_URL/${locale}${router.asPath}`}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </Head>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```